# Left joining a table's id with the maximum id from a subquery

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am using .NET core and trying to write a Linq query to list Cases. I have 3 tables that I am trying to join together:
Cases - Includes CaseID and CaseStatusID
CaseStatuses - Includes CaseStatusID (a Case has one of these)
CaseStatusHistory - Includes CaseStatusHistoryID, CaseID, CaseStatusID (a Case has many of these).

I can join Cases and CaseStatuses easily on CaseStatusID but am not sure how to join CaseStatusHistory on CaseStatusHistoryID = a subquery selecting the MAX(CaseStatusHistoryID) WHERE CaseID and CaseStatusID matches. I could even select the CaseStatusHitory later in my results but am not sure how.

This is what I need to convert

```
SELECT
            c.CaseID,
            csh.DateTimeAdded
        FROM dbo.Cases c
        JOIN dbo.CaseStatuses cs
            ON c.CaseStatusID = cs.CaseStatusID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CaseStatusHistory csh
            ON csh.CaseStatusHistoryID =
            (
                SELECT MAX(CaseStatusHistoryID)
                FROM dbo.CaseStatusHistory
                WHERE CaseID = c.CaseID
                    AND cs.CaseStatusID = c.CaseStatusID
            )
```

This is what I have so far in Linq

```
            IQueryable<CasesViewModel> objs =
                from c in _db.Cases
                from cs in _db.CaseStatuses.Where(cs => cs.CaseStatusId == c.CaseStatusId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new CasesViewModel
                {
                    CaseID = c.CaseId,
                    CaseStatus = cs.CaseStatus
                    //StatusChangeDate = csh.DateTimeAdded
                };
```

I need to add something like this

```
From csh In CaseStatusHistories
    Where
    (
        From _csh In CaseStatusHistories
        Where _csh.CaseID = c.CaseID AndAlso _csh.CaseStatusID = c.CaseStatusID
        Select _csh.CaseStatusHistoryID
    ).Max = csh.CaseStatusHistoryID
```

Here is what I have so far but it does not return any result - just seems to time out.

```
IQueryable<CasesViewModel> objs =
                from c in _db.Cases
                from cs in _db.CaseStatuses.Where(cs => cs.CaseStatusId == c.CaseStatusId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from rg in _db.RepairingGarages.Where(rg => rg.RepairingGarageId == c.RepairingGarageId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from rgb in _db.Businesses.Where(rgb => rgb.BusinessId == rg.BusinessId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from ec in _db.EngineeringCompanies.Where(ec => ec.EngineeringCompanyId == c.EngineeringCompanyId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from ecb in _db.Businesses.Where(ecb => ecb.BusinessId == ec.BusinessId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from csh in _db.CaseStatusHistory.Where(csh => csh.CaseStatusHistoryId ==
                (
                    from _csh in _db.CaseStatusHistory
                    where _csh.CaseId == c.CaseId && _csh.CaseStatusId == c.CaseStatusId.Value
                    select _csh.CaseStatusHistoryId
                ).Max()).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new CasesViewModel
                {
                    CaseID = c.CaseId,
                    RepairingGarage = rgb.BusinessName,
                    Engineer = ecb.BusinessName,
                    CaseStatus = cs.CaseStatus,
                    StatusChangeDate = csh.DateTimeAdded
                };
```

I just need to get the StatusChangeDate which is the DateTimeAdded in the CaseStatusHistory table. Cases can be at the same status more than once, so I just need the DateTimeAdded with the highest CaseStatusHistoryID for a particular Case. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to answer my question

```
IQueryable<CasesViewModel> objs =
                from c in _db.Cases
                from cs in _db.CaseStatuses.Where(cs => cs.CaseStatusId == c.CaseStatusId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from rg in _db.RepairingGarages.Where(rg => rg.RepairingGarageId == c.RepairingGarageId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from rgb in _db.Businesses.Where(rgb => rgb.BusinessId == rg.BusinessId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from ec in _db.EngineeringCompanies.Where(ec => ec.EngineeringCompanyId == c.EngineeringCompanyId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                from ecb in _db.Businesses.Where(ecb => ecb.BusinessId == ec.BusinessId.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new CasesViewModel
                {
                    CaseID = c.CaseId,
                    RepairingGarage = rgb.BusinessName,
                    Engineer = ecb.BusinessName,
                    CaseStatus = cs.CaseStatus,
                    StatusChangeDate =
                    (
                        from _csh in _db.CaseStatusHistory
                        where _csh.CaseId == c.CaseId && _csh.CaseStatusId == cs.CaseStatusId
                        orderby _csh.CaseStatusHistoryId descending
                        select _csh.DateTimeAdded
                    ).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

The only trouble with not joining is that I am not sure if I can sort by this date now. Any better ideas? Thank you.